# Different checkbox option redirect to new link on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reposting this question. You can view the section in question at the following link:
https://habitat-df.webflow.io/site-web/nos-realisations#listings
I am using a CMS called webflow.

**The problem:**
I have created 4 different pages for when the user chooses the options and clicks on submit.
The submit button has the id "button-submit"

**Different name attribute to the checkboxes:**

- For rent project- the name value is: rent
- For sale project - the name value is: sale
- For past project - the name value is: past
- For current projects - the name value is: recent

This is the Jquery code I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#button-submit').click(function(){
         var checkValue = jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').val();

         if ((checkValue == 'sale') && (checkValue == 'past')){
              window.location.href = 'page1.com';
         }
         if ((checkValue == 'sale') && (checkValue == 'recent')) {
              window.location.href = 'page2.com';
         }
         if ((checkValue == 'rent') && (checkValue == 'past')){
              window.location.href = 'page3.com';
         }
         if ((checkValue == 'rent') && (checkValue == 'recent')){
              window.location.href = 'page4.com';
         }
    })
});
```

Here is the HTML part of the form:

```
    <div class="w-form">
      <form id="wf-form-Choice-form" name="wf-form-Choice-form" data-name="Choice form" method="post">
        <h2 class="h2-big titreprojet"><strong>Découvrez NoTRE PORTFOLIO</strong><br></h2>
        <div class="lineprojet"></div>
        <div class="description">Notre caractère distinctif, c’est d’avoir réalisé des projets de qualité, tout en procurant une expérience unique à nos clients. <br></div>
        <div class="w-row">
          <div class="column-16 w-col w-col-6">
            <div class="smalltext">Type de projet</div><label class="w-checkbox fieldlocation"><input type="checkbox" id="rent" name="rent" data-name="rent" class="w-checkbox-input"><span for="rent" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projet en location</span></label><label class="w-checkbox fieldsale"><input type="checkbox" id="sale" name="sale" data-name="sale" class="w-checkbox-input"><span for="sale" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projet en vente</span></label></div>
          <div class="w-col w-col-6">
            <div class="smalltext">DATE DU PROJET</div><label class="w-checkbox fieldactuel"><input type="checkbox" id="recent" name="recent" data-name="recent" class="w-checkbox-input"><span for="recent" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projet actuel</span></label><label class="w-checkbox fieldpast"><input type="checkbox" id="past" name="past" data-name="past" class="w-checkbox-input"><span for="past" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projet passé</span></label></div>
        </div><input type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait..." id="button-submit" class="button-submit w-button"></form>
      <div class="w-form-done">
        <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-form-fail">
        <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The HTML looks messed up because I am exporting it from webflow who gives custom values to everything on export. When I test my custom code, nothing works, no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not tested, but I guess jquery.val() returns the value and not the name. You don't set the value attribute and so there's no value, non of your if statements matches and so "nothing happens". Use your browsers debuger to verify this.

Comment: what do you get when you write `console.log(checkValue);` after `var checkValue = jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').val();`? You will see the response in the browser's developer console. It helps a lot in web dev.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but there are some small mistakes.

```
         var checkValue = jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').val();
```

Will only give you one output. Thus, all your if conditions will fails since you are assuming that it can hold two values.

So create another variable that holds the value of the date (recent or past) and a variable for holding (sale or rent).

Also it's better if you change the button type to submit so it actually submits the form and it's input to a certain page. Otherwise you are not actually making use of this form. I recommend that you remove the form in this case since it's not needed.

Also make use of [jQuery Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp), they will make your life much easier for example assign a class name or an id to the elements and get them through `$('#id')` or `$('.classname')` or `$('tagname')`. ($ is short hand for JQuery)

I'm a bit at hurry therefore sorry if I couldn't give you a complete answer, but hey at least you know where to go. :)

Cheers.

Comment: I will try this and let you know! thank you for the clear answer!